# Is it possible Cloneing git over SSH with full path to the repo?

Tags: ssh, git

I use satis to generate my private list of packages for composer. Unfortunately, satis refuses to accept **ssh://user@myserv.com:port/MyRepoName.git** syntax. The only syntax it accepts is **ssh://user@myserv.com:port/home/git/repositories/MyRepoName.git** (so, adding the full path to the repo).

With such syntax satis generates packages.json with such URLs:
**ssh://user@myserv.com:port/home/git/repositories/MyRepoName.git**

But when I try (from my client machine) to clone it - it does not work (Repository not found).

I can only clone useing the short (**ssh://user@myserv.com:port/MyRepoName.git**) syntax.

So my question is: is there any configuration I can change either on server (ubuntu 12.04 with gitolite) or client (Windows7 + composer) to make cloneing of **ssh://user@myserv.com:port/home/git/repositories/MyRepoName.git** possible?

I've created an issue in satis project, but before they fix that it might take a while. I need to make full path syntax URL working as a temporary solution.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you give wrong path for it, actually.

Try using `ssh://user@myserv.com:port//home/git/repositories/MyRepoName.git`, may be.

Also, I don't think you have to specify port at all, it's kinda redundant unless you have ssh listening somewhere else.

**UPD.:** In case everything is really so bad with the soft you use, you can create symlink to rootfs in user's directory, say `ln -s / rootfs`, then `git clone ssh://user@myserv.com:port/rootfs/home/…bla…bla…`

Comment: unfortunately I have to add the port in satis configuration, otherwise it won't build (generate) packages.json; thx for answer ill try your proposition and let you know if it worked!

Comment: no, unfortunately it didnt work :(

Comment: So, the full path is `/home/git/repositories/MyRepoName.git`, right?

Comment: @PiotrGołębiewski, see upd. also.